# Prove that variance of estimator in GLS is less than variance of estimator in OLS

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, regression

In my statistics class we showed that for Ordinary Least Squares regression:

$$
var[\hat{\beta}_{OLS}] = (X^TX)^{-1}X^T\sigma^2X(X^TX)^{-1}
$$

and for Generalized Least Squares regression (ie. allowing the errors to be heteroskedastic):

$$
var[\hat{\beta}_{GLS}] = (X^T(\sigma^2)^{-1}X)^{-1}
$$

where for GLS the variance matrix is still diagonal but the components are not necessarily all equal as they are assumed to be for OLS.

We were told that

$$
var[\hat{\beta}_{GLS}] < var[\hat{\beta}_{OLS}] 
$$

How can we prove that this is the case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/496112/how-to-prove-positive-semi-definitness-in-matrix-notation-without-numbers/496131#496131